# How to use @apollo/server and @as-integrations/next in new experimental app folder in next js 13.2.1

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-server

I created a file at app/api/graphql.ts. The route is /api/graphql. But there is no action, only 404:This page could not be found.

I tried this guide https://github.com/apollo-server-integrations/apollo-server-integration-next. In this, Next.js API route will be /api/graphql by creating a file at for example pages/api/graphql.ts.

Then I wonder if this @as-integration/next only works in previous version of NEXT JS. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In graphql.ts, to start a basic server you can follow this code below with your defined resolvers and typeDefs. I abstracted those out into a separate file, but you can also have them in this file.

```
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from '@as-integrations/next';
import resolvers from './resolvers/resolvers'
import typeDefs from './schema/schema'

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

export default startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by following the instructions at https://github.com/apollo-server-integrations/apollo-server-integration-next to create a new file at `app/api/route.ts` with the following content:

```
import handler from "./graphql";

export async function GET(request) {
  return handler(request);
}

export async function POST(request) {
  return handler(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from '@as-integrations/next';
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag';

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello: () => 'world',
    },
};

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

const server = new ApolloServer({
    resolvers,
    typeDefs,
});

const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler<NextRequest>(server, {
    context: async req => ({ req }),
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

using this dependencies

```
{
  "name": "graphql-server-client-nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.10.0",
    "@as-integrations/next": "^3.0.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Result:
[image: running in http://localhost:3000/api/graphql]